# Error (undefined variable) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is that JSON feed returning an undefined variables while working for other variable? What am I doing wrong or overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to say as provided link will return an error (Invalid parameter value: callback=?). If I remove the callback parameter from the url, the answer to your question is obvious, but I don't know if the data is valid.

Comment: @ybo, remove callback=? from link when rendering in browser and it return data as normal. callback=? is need to parse data with $.getJSON. Removing callback=? from URL does not return anything when using $.getJSON.

Comment: JSON structure is fine, but the `item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url']` and `tem['yt$statistics']['viewCount']` don't exist in the returned data. Are you sure that user account is correct and is active?

Comment: @k prime, you seem right, the account holder must have removed their favorites because I had copied the returned json data from earlier and was just now starting to assign the var and parsing it. Now testing with another account just to make sure it work.

Comment: Now using this URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/soccerdude1935/favorites?alt=json-in-script (account is active and it is returning all data) and I still error message when assigning var to item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'], item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'], and item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['duration'] even though they are present in the returned data.

Comment: I edited my answer -- please note that not all items in response contain item['media$group']['media$content'] array.

Comment: Thanks again Priit. See my updated post above.

Comment: Revised the question. Would really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the contents in response:

```
curl http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/kaycor/favorites?alt=json-in-script&callback=mycallback
```

You see that entry.media$group and entry.yt$statistics are not there:

```
gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded({
    "feed": {
        // snip ...
        "entry": [{
            // snip ...
            "media$group": {
                "media$category": [{
                    // snip ...
                }],
                "media$title": {
                    // snip ...
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Not all items contain the `media$content` array, so you should modify your each block  to something like this:

```
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
    var uploader = item['author'][0]['name']['$t'];
    if (item['media$group']['media$content']) {
        var URL = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
        var thum = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
    }
});
```

I wrote a quick test script for this and with the if clause in place, it did not throw errors anymore.

Comment: @Priit, thanks for your reply. You're right, I just notice that the returned data from the account I was using is no longer returning those data since I retrieved the data earlier and was just now assigning variables. Updated my post. Still getting an error when assigning var to returned data.

Comment: @Priit, thanks a lot for your continuous help. Vote up for you sir. Almost there (thumb var does not work for some reason even with an if statement). See my latest update above and let me know if you have any suggestions.